# Retrieving Multiple funds using investpy under a specific form

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm new to python and i want to get output in this form plz :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYUoP.png)

Instead of this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5DSE.png)

My code

```
import investpy as inv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

funds = ["Pluvalca Allcaps A", "Moneta Multi Caps C", "Renaissance Europe I"]
dfs = pd.DataFrame()

for fund in funds:
    df = investpy.get_fund_recent_data(fund=fund, country='france') 
    dfs = dfs.append(df.Close[-1:],ignore_index = True)
dfs = dfs.T
dfs.columns = funds
dff = np.transpose(dfs)
dfs.head()
dff.head()
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to the StackOverflow community. Please see this question to ask questions more and more effectively. Tell us more about what you want and what errors you get, and where you stuck? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: You made a mistake in calling `investpy` function. You must use alias `inv` instead of `investpy`. `df = inv.get_fund_recent_data(fund=fund, country='france')`

Comment: Thank you Zalak i got this message error ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 2 elements

Comment: Thank you Iman, i what i want is given by the 1st image.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following modification when creating `dff`.

```
import investpy as inv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

funds = ["Pluvalca Allcaps A", "Moneta Multi Caps C", "Renaissance Europe I"]
dfs = pd.DataFrame()

for fund in funds:
    df = inv.get_fund_recent_data(fund=fund, country='france') 
    dfs = dfs.append(df.Close[-1:], ignore_index=True)
dfs = dfs.T
dfs.columns = funds
dff = np.transpose(dfs)
date1 = dff.columns[0]
dff["Date"] = date1
dff.columns = ["Close", "Date"]
dff.head()
```